# How do I render ReactJS component with filtered props?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I've made a filter where I check if some string is equal to the category described as a property in an  array(work props). This array is a restAPI object with postitems from Wordpress. 
What I wan't to achieve is straight forward I think.
For visualising my filter I used a pre-fab solution from React-select node_module to show my filters.

**Approach**

If my (react-select) dropdown filter is not selected or the page is just mounded, it should show a full list with posts. Else if I select an option from the dropdown filter e.g 'UX design' It should show a filtered list with post items categorized with 'Ux design'

I created the below functional example where I check if the dropdown(react-select) is selected with a filter or not.
Unfortunately when I select the react-select dropdown and filter trough the original prop 'work' I do not get back a rendered list but a warning. What mistake do I make here?

```
render (){
            const { work } = this.props;
            const { selectedOption } = this.state;

            return selectedOption === null ? (
            <RenderOverview work={work} />
            ) : (
            <RenderOverview
                work={work.map(value => {
                    let type = value.pure_taxonomies.types[0].name;
                    if (type === selectedOption.label) {
                        return value;
                    }
                })}
            />
           );

}
```

In my console I got back after running the script.

```
47:42  warning  Expected to return a value at the end of this function array-callback-return
```

Comment: You should use `filter` instead of `map` because map will always return something, if you skipped the return it will return undefined as the item of the new array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), if you did not return something in your map function, it will return `undefined` as your item in your new array.

You can write your render as the following, you always return `<RenderOverview>` component, and if there is a selected option, filter your `work` based on the selected option, otherwise use back the original `work` list.

```
return (
    <RenderOverview
        work={selectedOption ? work.filter(value => value.pure_taxonomies.types[0].name === selectedOption.label) : work}
    />
);
```

Comment: Thanks for this useful answer. You've helped me out.